# I am using window.history.replaceState to hide GET method's elements, but when I reload the page those elements are lost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using window.history.replaceState to hide GET method's elements, but when I reload the page those elements are lost. So, when I reload the page I am redirecting to the index.php. I am attaching the script I use.

```
<script> 
      if(typeof window.history.replaceState == 'function') { 
        window.history.replaceState({}, "Hide", ".#<?php echo $_GET["menu"];?>"); 
      } 
</script>
```

I will appreciate any answers who can help, or at least helpful links where I can find the answer.

Comment: If you change the URL of the page, reloading can no longer access the original URL. It is lost. If you want some parameters not to appear in the URL, you need to use a method such as POST. Or you can place a reload button somewhere with the right URL "hidden" inside in its onclick() method.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that my solution was something so simple! I will change the method from GET to POST.